# SFDX Question. Can source:status be used in sandboxes?

Tags: salesforcedx, vs-code

Quick question, can I use source:status on sandbox? I'm a sf developer and I am still learning how to use sfdx in org development model (since its the one we use) and was wondering if source:status works for sandbox? coz current I retrieved all my apex classes from our dev sandbox using source:retrieve and then tried to use source:status then an error poped up stating this error.

ERROR at Row:1:Column:52
sObject type 'SourceMember' is not supported. If you are attempting to use a custom object, be sure to append the '__c' after
the entity name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

Thanks for the help. Still learning sfdx. Hope someone can answer this question since i cant find any explicit answer to my question in any resource

Answer (score 8):

The [source tracking](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer20/release-notes/rn_sandboxes_source_tracking.htm) feature for developer and developer pro sandboxes is GA from the winter 21 release.

You will need to first enable this in DevHub and then refresh the sandbox from PROD to get this activated.

Comment: Whao! That's a relief. Will be looking forward on this one! Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Forgot to ask. May I ask for the reference where you got this news? thanks so much! would like to read more about it.

Comment: added the reference . check the talk here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FUqWc3sM0K0

Comment: Thank you so much!