# Will the new Lightning Developer Pro Sandboxes be source-tracking orgs?

Tags: salesforcedx, sandbox

As of Summer '19, [Lightning Developer Pro Sandboxes](https://developer.salesforce.com/promotions/ldps-pilot) are in pilot mode and you can sign up for them now.

I just wanted to know if the new LDPS orgs will be source-tracking or not (meaning, we can use `force:source:pull` and `push`, etc. like a scratch org)

My only source of reference thus far is the [Developer Keynote on LDPS from Dreamforce video](https://youtu.be/C6Cp2P5Eb7Y?t=1234) (kudos to the [BlueCanvas.io article](https://bluecanvas.io/blog/lightning-developer-pro-sandbox-for-salesforce) for introducing LDPS to me)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per @MohithShrivastava's post [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/269592/55891), looks like Sandboxes are  getting source-tracking abilities by Summer '20 (beta).